# Why do all procedures have to be defined before the compiler sees them?

Tags: scheme, racket, r6rs

For example, take a look at this code (from tspl4):

```
(define proc1
  (lambda (x y)
    (proc2 y x)))
```

If I run this as my program in scheme...

```
#!r6rs
(import (rnrs))

(define proc1
  (lambda (x y)
    (proc2 y x)))
```

I get this error:

```
expand: unbound identifier in module in: proc2
```

...This code works fine though:

```
#!r6rs
(import (rnrs))

(define proc2
  +)

(define proc1
  (lambda (x y)
    (proc2 y x)))

(display (proc1 2 3)) ;output: 5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They all have to be defined in the same module (= "library" in r6rs lingo).  But you can define them in any order you want -- for example, in your last snip you can swap the two definitions and it will work fine.  But note that you cannot put the definitions after the `display` line -- this is an expression that uses their *value*, so if you move the function definitions after it, you'll get a runtime error.  (Note the fact that it's a *runtime* error rather than a compile-time one.)

Comment: If it's a runtime error, then why does my first program crash? It doens't even run proc1, so why would it need proc2? tspl4 says it shouldn't crash.

Comment: Think about it as a linking problem: PLT actually compiles your code, and you have a reference that the compiler doesn't know about.